# Strip HTML contents using SED

Tags: html, sed, strip, stripping

I am working on a task for which SED is the designated tool.
The task is to strip the contents of any web page file (*.htm or *.html), and insert the desired data into a new file.

- Everything before and including the `<body>` tag is to be removed.
- Everything from and including the `</body>` tag is to be removed.

Below is one example, where `<div>` tags, and what's between them, is to be kept:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>SED Challange</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;"><div style="width:100%; height:150px; margin-top:150px; text-align:center">
<img src="pic.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Pic alt text" />
</div></body></html>
```

However, I'm having trouble with removing `<body>` and what comes before:

```
sed 's/.*body.*>//' ./index.html > ./index.html.nobody
```

Instead of the desired result, the two separate lines containing `<body>` and `</body>` are removed!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>SED Challange</title>
</head>

<img src="pic.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Pic alt text" />
```

I can't see why even one would be. I appreciate any feedback.

Edit:

Thanks to SLePort, this is my complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Search location as user provided argument.
target="$1"

#Recursive, case insensitive search for file extension like htm(l).
hit=$(find $target -type f -iname '*.htm' -or -iname '*.html')

for h in $hit
do
    hp=$(realpath $h) #Absolute path of file (hit path).
    echo "Stripping performed on $hp" #Informing what file(s) found.
    nobody="${hp}_nobody" #File to contain desired data ending with "_nobody".

    #Remove file contents from start to and including head-tag, 
    #Remove body-tag,
    #Remove end html-tag,
    #Removee blank lines,
    #Insert data from file to file_nobody.
    sed '1,/<\/head>/d;s/<\/*body[^>]*>//g;s/<\/html>//;/^$/d' $h > $nobody 
done
```

Comment: so, the result should be `<div style="width:100%; height:150px; margin-top:150px; text-align:center"><img src="pic.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Pic alt text" /></div>` ?

Comment: Correct Roman, for this particular content, that is true. 
As the task is declared, desired data to collect is between the BODY tags.
For a different source file there might not be DIV tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sed should work with the given code:

```
sed '1,/<\/head>/d;s/<\/*body[^>]*>//g;s/<\/html>//' ./index.html > ./index.html.nobody
```

It removes :

- lines from line 1 to `</head>` tag
- `<body>` and `</body>` tags
- `</html>` closing tag

But note that sed is NOT for parsing html files. Use an xml parser instead (eg: [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/),...)

Comment: SLePort, thanks for input. It had no effect for me, I'm afraid.
I'm trying to have the script explicitly remove everything to and including the BODY tag. There might not be a DIV tag in a different source material.

Comment: Thanks SLePort, I say you did it! Apologies for late reply, I've been working on completing the script.